# Unable to draw a network graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

**This is my code:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
nx.draw(G)

plt.show()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Normally, a graph is defined as a collection of nodes and edges. You haven't added any edges to the graph, yet.
For example:

```
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
```